# Add at command to docker

Tags: docker, at-job

Hello i want to add [At](https://linuxize.com/post/at-command-in-linux/) command to docker container. I am using linux alpine .
I tried to use `apk add at` and`apk add atd` it is giving me the same error.

> **ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:   atd (missing):
> required by: world[atd]**

Is there a way to fix that or can is there a way to use apt-get since at exists for apt-get

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile.

Comment: hi i have already a docker file which is used for the company i run it inside the docker instance of the object

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `at` just available as is: `apk add at`

this `Dockerfile` works fine for me:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add at
CMD at --help
```

example run:

```sh
$ docker build -t at_command_line  -f Dockerfile .
$ docker run at_command_line:latest 
at: unrecognized option: -
Usage: at [-V] [-q x] [-f file] [-u username] [-mMlbv] timespec ...
       at [-V] [-q x] [-f file] [-u username] [-mMlbv] -t time
       at -c job ...
       atq [-V] [-q x]
       at [ -rd ] job ...
       atrm [-V] job ...
       batch
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add to @ujlbu4's answer that you need to run the at daemon `atd` once your container is up and running or else the jobs will sit in the queue without getting executed.

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN apk add at
ENTRYPOINT ["atd"]
```

If you don't run `atd` you may see the following:

```
$ docker exec -it my_running_container /bin/sh
# echo "echo hi" | at now + 1 minutes
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 6 at Mon Jun 21 18:11:00 2021
Can't open /var/run/atd.pid to signal atd. No atd running?
```